# SharePoint 2007 issue, Users getting automatically added

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have a MOSS (SharePoint 2007) site. We have granted Limited Access to a SharePoint group, In that group we added an AD group. So who ever part of the AD group will have the limited access to the Site. But when they access other resources they are redirected to request access page. Even i'm getting their access request email. But system automatically adds the user to the site. When i look into the User Information in the People and Group, the user is already added into the system (without me providing access). The 'Created by' property showing the as requester name itself. Is there any way to track this issue. I tried to replicate it, but this is not reproducible. But still the issue occurs sometime.

Answer (score 1):

The user is added automatically to the *User Information List* the first time he or she accesses the site collection. At this moment their information is synchronized with the User Content Database.

> WSS maintains the profile data for external users, groups, and roles
>   in a hidden list, which is known as the User Information List. Every
>   time WSS provisions a new site collection, it automatically creates
>   the User Information List as a hidden list in the top-level site.
>   **WSS then adds a new profile for each external principal the first time that principal is assigned permission or the first time it passes
>   a security check to access a securable object**. Note that the user
>   profile stored in the User Information List does not extend across
>   site collections—when users update their profile settings in one site
>   collection, there are no changes to that user's profile settings in
>   other site collections.

Source: [Security Programming in SharePoint 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163287.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for the answer, but i couldn't reproduce this behavior, is there any way to test it out? I have did the following steps. Added a user into a site collection in the same farm. And after some time i asked the user to visit another site and request access. But the user is not added to the second site automatically.

Comment: The _User Information List (UIL)_ is stored at the site collection level. There are no _UIL_ s at the (sub)site level. If you add an user to any subsite, it will be added in the _UIL_ at the site collection level. The same stands true for groups. Giving permissions is a different thing: the user needs to be given specifically permissions and/or he/she needs to be added to a group to have access to a site or site resource.